# Xcode compile error: Use of undeclared identifier 'make_shared'

Tags: c++, c++11, osx-mavericks, xcode5.1, make-shared

I have ported some code which compiles well with VS2012 to Mac.
But now the Xcode blurts out an error that it does not recognise the function "make_shared".
which is part of c++11.

I have declared the following:

```
#include <tr1/memory>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::tr1;
class BaseClass {};
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {};
```

This is the code:

```
shared_ptr< BaseClass > foo = make_shared< DerivedClass >("some param");
```

I have upgraded to Mac OSX Mavericks,
and to Xcode Version 5.1.1 (5B1008)
I have set the compiler to the following settings:

1. compile sources as objective-c++
2. c++ language dialects c++11 [-std=c++11]
3. c++ standard library: libstdc++ (gnu c++ standard library)

Comment: `tr1` isn't really part of `C++11`, have you tried including `<memory>` rather than `<tr1/memory>`?

Comment: Yes I have tried that as well. But the compiler shrieked and ordered me to use <tr1/memory>

Comment: If you want the C++11 standard library on you should use `libc++`, not `libstdc++`. Xcode ships an ancient version of `libstdc++` that is only there for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Yes, I have tried both **libc++** & **libstdc++**

Comment: In that case I have no idea what is going wrong... worksforme™. Sorry.